# Transparency only rendering on one side?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

So for context I'm using Cycles Render. As you can see in the image below, when I go to render my transparent cube it renders as transparent on one side and then the other sides are left a solid color. I thought it was a lighting issue so I added multiple light sources, specifically to that side but no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Transparent Cube]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning up your transparency bounces.

Comment: Oh lord, my mistake. I hadn't added a Transparent BSDF as I have it set to look like glass. I added one after this though and it worked so cheers!